# C++ Class Inheritance and assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, binary, operator-keyword

I came here to ask something I can't figure out on my own. I've been coding a little class that stores an array of 32 bits and can perform simple mathematic operations like <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>*</kbd>.

Suppose I have a class like:

```
class Binary_Class
{
  char bin[32];               // 32 bits array to hold an unsigned binary number
  void set_dec(int value){};  // setting the bin[32] value based on input value

  // I have operator + and = to perform on objects of this class.
  Binary_Class& operator= (const Binary_Class&);
  const Binary_Class operator+ (const Binary_Class&);
}
```

Until now, no problem comes up if i declare 3 objects `a`,`b`,`c` of class `Binary_Class`, then `set_dec` to `a` and `b`, the statement `c=a+b` can be used (?)

However, I want to extend the class binary by using a new class

```
class Binary_Class_Extended: public Binary_Class
{
  // weird functions
}
```

If I declare 3 objects `a`, `b`, `c` of class `Binary_Class_Extended`, am I still able to use `c=a+b` as the same before that?

In Netbean it says there's no operator= that match my `c=a+b` if all are of `Binary_Class_Extended`,
but if I declare `c` as `Binary_Class` that statement works. That means `a+b` returns a `const Binary_Class` as if the `operator+` doesn't get carried to the new class.

Am I missing something or this is the way it is?

Of course, I can post the whole code because it's just an assignment but I think these infos are enough for now.

---

Update

```
 class Binary_Class
 {
  char bin[32];               // 32 bits array to hold an unsigned binary number
  void set_dec(int value){};  // setting the bin[32] value based on input value

  //i have operator + and = to perform on objects of this class.
  Binary_Class& operator= (const Binary_Class&);
  const Binary_Class operator+ (const Binary_Class&) const;
}

class Binary_Class_Extended: public Binary_Class
{
  // weird functions
}
```

When I try to have all objects of `Binary_Class_Extended` this error show up:

> main.cpp:285: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'sd = ((Binary_Class*)(&sa))->Binary_Class::operator+(((const Binary_Class&)((const Binary_Class*)((Binary_Class*)(&sb)))))'

`Binary_ET_Class sa,sb,sc;`

`sc=sa+sb` //initialized `sa` and `sb` to non-null value;

The full source code I've been working on: https://pastebin.com/eiVz0f5p

Comment: Please use proper capitalization.

Comment: Ah, thanks for correcting the post. My mind wasn't focus on that at the time, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherited functions retain their finger prints, so if the Binary_Class operator+ was inherited, it's return value would be ... ?

Comment: Ah, what a simple answer. I think I've treated those so called operator differently. They're just functions right?
So if I want to retain the function of thte operator+ I shall write one in the new class, shouldn't I?

Comment: Yep -- one other thing occurred to me; your operator+ isn't const, and it probably should be -- operator "+" is used for `x = a + b` but it is used on a and b, not on x. So you probably want `const Binary_Class& operator+(const Binary_Class& src) const;`. See http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html. Your Binary_Class_Extended can kill two birds with one stone by defining it as `const Binary_Class_Extended& operator+(const Binary_Class& rhs) const;` and allowing it to take the base class rather than the derived class.

Comment: oh ive come across that paged and read that too but missed that last `const` after the bracket.

this is the error when all are of Binary_Class_Extended, and i don't redeclare = and + operator on that class aka the operator= error i mentioned in the question: 

`main.cpp:285: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'sd = ((Binary_Class*)(&sa))->Binary_Class::operator+(((const Binary_Class&)((const Binary_Class*)((Binary_Class*)(&sb)))))'`

Comment: Can you append this to the original post along with the updated code so I can see it more easily?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eiVz0f5p I pasted it here the full source, hope you can try and read my messy code if you don't mind. I'll update the post right away

Comment: I tried compiling the code at the paste with GCC 4.7.2 and -std=c++11, it compiled ok, but -Wall revealed that you have a bug at line 159 where you write beyond the end of the "bin" array.

Comment: Ah - ok - re-read the extra details in the original post. I would write out the problem line in detail, e.g. `(Binary_Class_Extended:1) sa = (Binary_Class_Extended:2) sb [const:1] / (Binary_Class_Extended:3) sd [const:2];` which means it is invoking `Binary_Class_Extended& Binary_Class_Extended :: operator/ (const:2 Binary_Class_Extended&) const:1;`

Comment: Ah my bad again, I supposed to write `sc=sa+sb` but my code was being used to test the division function at the time... can you try that statement.

Comment: That's because it's falling thru to the operator+ in the Binary_Class, which returns a Binary_Class. If you want to be able to add Binary_Class_Extended, you're going to have to implement a Binary_Class_Extended operator + which does that. See http://ideone.com/yohCJy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679073/overloading-operators-in-derived-class

Answer (score 1):

In general, inheritance and assignment ("value semantics") don't mix easily in C++. In your second case, the "a+b" would return an instance of the baseclass, unless you define a separator operator+ for the derived class. The result is then only assigned to the base-class part of "c", which is triggering the error. This is also sometimes call slicing/truncation. Note that the choice of the operator is at compile time, no virtual functions are called, so the static type has to match.

Don't mix value types and polymorphic types. If you really need to and you have a fixed and known hierarchy, you can use the "Handle-Body Idiom" to preserve derived information when assigning to the baseclass. This is not a beginner topic though.

Comment: Oh, so they don't carry the operator to the child? What I think is that the new class "inherit" all the good of the base class and if I don't re-define the operator + then the function remain the same, only change the class from `Binary_Class` to `Binary_Class_Extended`.
The purpose of the new class is to extend functionality of the base class by providing additional functions to it, but I think I have failed to achieve that because the original functions (like operator+) is lost (can't perform on the new class).